# Route laravel weirdly error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have some problem about routes in laravel

```php
Route::get('aset/create', 'TransaksiController@aset_create');
Route::get('aset/{id}', 'TransaksiController@aset_view');
```

these routes was fine, but when i switch the position like

```php
Route::get('aset/{id}', 'TransaksiController@aset_view');
Route::get('aset/create', 'TransaksiController@aset_create');
```

the `aset/create` was went to `aset/view`

[image]

whats happening?
thanks!

Comment: Did you defined what [type of parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) is `id`? If not, that's probably the problem, the word `create` matchs `{id}`.

Comment: yes youre right thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aset/create` will trigger the `Route::get('aset/{id}', 'TransaksiController@aset_view');` as you can see the template displayed is for view `aset-view.blade.php` not the template for the create, so laravel identifies `create` as the `id` param so your db query will return no rows creating the error you see,

To fix this problem you either keep the original order or you change the view route to match only number(or not match `create`)

```
Route::get('aset/{id}', 'TransaksiController@aset_view')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

`aset-view.blade.php` file, that's where you have issue. You are either accessing a variable as object, it could be something `null` or array which you are accessing as an object

Answer (score 0):

{id} is a parameter for passing it is receving now create as parameter.since it is in top.Rearrange will solve the problem.id will catch anything you pass